# JPanels will not show up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm making a simple GUI calculator. Before I insert the guts, I'm trying to get the GUI down. The problem that I'm having is that my `JPanels` containing the keypad and display will not show up in the main `JFrame` for the program. What am I missing?

**Main:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        calc();
    }

    public final void calc() {
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Alex's Calculator");
        Display disp = new Display();
        Keypad keyp = new Keypad();
        JPanel c = new JPanel();

        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add(disp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(keyp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setSize(400, 300);
        c.setVisible(true);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Keypad:** (Yes, I know. I'm going to add a loop to create an array of buttons.)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Keypad extends JPanel{

    public Keypad() {

        int num = 1;
        JPanel Keypad = new JPanel();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton bDec = new JButton(".");
        JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
        JButton bPlus = new JButton("+");
        JButton bMinus = new JButton("-");
        JButton bDiv = new JButton("/");
        JButton bMult = new JButton("*");
        JButton bBOR = new JButton("|");
        JButton bBAND = new JButton("&");
        JButton bModu = new JButton("%");
        JButton bEq = new JButton("=");
        JButton bC = new JButton("Clear");   

        Keypad.add(b1);
        b1.setMnemonic('1');

        Keypad.add(b2);
        b2.setMnemonic('2');

        Keypad.add(b3);
        b3.setMnemonic('3');

        Keypad.add(bPlus);
        bPlus.setMnemonic('+');

        Keypad.add(bBOR);
        bBOR.setMnemonic('|');

        Keypad.add(b4);
        b4.setMnemonic('4');

        Keypad.add(b5);
        b5.setMnemonic('5');

        Keypad.add(b6);
        b6.setMnemonic('6');

        Keypad.add(bMinus);
        bMinus.setMnemonic('-');

        Keypad.add(bBAND);
        bBAND.setMnemonic('&');

        Keypad.add(b7);
        b7.setMnemonic('7');

        Keypad.add(b8);
        b8.setMnemonic('8');

        Keypad.add(b9);
        b9.setMnemonic('9');

        Keypad.add(bMult);
        bMult.setMnemonic('*');

        Keypad.add(bModu);
        bModu.setMnemonic('%');

        Keypad.add(b0);
        b0.setMnemonic('0');

        Keypad.add(bDec);
        bDec.setMnemonic('.');

        Keypad.add(bC);
        bC.setMnemonic('C');

        Keypad.add(bDiv);
        bDiv.setMnemonic('/');

        Keypad.add(bEq);
        bEq.setMnemonic('=');  

        Keypad.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5));

        Keypad.setSize(400, 200);
        Keypad.setVisible(true);
    }  
}
```

**Display:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Display extends JPanel{

    JTextField result = new JTextField(20);

    public Display() {
        JPanel display = new JPanel();

        display.setLayout(new BoxLayout(display, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        display.add(result);
        display.setSize(400, 100);
        result.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        result.setEditable(false);
        display.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Java, and to programming as a whole.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You need to call `main.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);` to add `JPanel c` to your frame. Make sure to do this as one of the first things you do to `main`.
2. In your JPanels, you are creating objects locally that are never returned from the classes.

More discussion on #2 below. But first, your `Main` class itself is already a JFrame, so you really don't need to create a separate JFrame called `main`. Instead, do this:

```
    Display disp = new Display();
    Keypad keyp = new Keypad();

    JPanel c = new JPanel();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c.add(disp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(keyp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setTitle("Alex's Calculator");
    this.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(400, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Now back to those JPanels. In both cases, you create JPanel objects (`Keypad` and `display`) but those are never returned from the classes. Instead, make sure you're working with the fact that your classes extend JPanel - in other words, work on `this` instead of creating a separate object. For example, your new `Display` should look like:

```
public Display() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(display, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    this.add(result);
    this.setSize(400, 100);
    result.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    result.setEditable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I added main.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER); and still nothing. Then, I decided to try adding main.pack();. When I did, my JFrame came up sized at about 10x10. That leads me to believe that the components aren't invisible, but just aren't there at all.

Comment: Added some additional details to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working. If I had enough reputation, I would upvote your answer.